# Drupal: Overriding user-profile.tpl: "print theme('username', $user);" shows the logged in user´s name instead of the profile owner

Tags: drupal, profile

Well, as the title says, I´m trying to override the whole user profile template in a Drupal 6 installation.

This is what I´ve got so far:

```
<h1><?php print theme('username', $user); ?>  &nbsp;<a class="btn btn-primary btn-mini" href="/user/<?php print $user->uid;?>/edit">edit my account</a> &nbsp;<a class="btn btn-danger btn-mini" href="/user/<?php print $user->uid;?>/profile/perfil">edit my profile node</a>&nbsp;<a class="btn btn-mini" href="/logout"><b>log out</b></a></h1>
  <br><?php print $user_profile; ?>
```

The idea is to take over the profile to show no tabs:

USERNAME [edit account button] [edit nodeprofile button]
[everything else that´s usually inside the user profile]

**My problem is that the code above, shows the logged in user username (and the edit buttons) instead of the profile owner´s.**
$user_profile; is working ok, because the stuff that shows after the buttons is the profile owner´s.

How should I twist that to act as I want it to?

Thanks!!!

Rosamunda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case someone wonders, I´ve just been able to find the answer and wanted to share it:

```
<?php echo $account->uid;?>
<?php echo $account->name;?>
```

As I´ve learn, if you want to show the logged in user, you use USER, when you refer to the accoun´t owner, you simply use ACCOUNT.

Cheers,

Rosamunda

Comment: Se the comments in user-profile.tpl.php. You will see that $profile and $account contains all the data you need.